# How to load (map) thousands of files as fast as possible?

Tags: c++, performance, file-mapping

I want to load the content of thousands of files with different sizes (1KB ~ 50MB) on Windows.

Currently, I am using the mapping library from [here](https://github.com/d0k/mappedfile), but it is still too slow, even with the std::async solution.

```
void RegisterArchives(const std::vector<std::string_view>& archives)
{
    std::vector<std::future<bool>> archives_vector;
    archives_future.reserve(archives.size());

    for (auto& i : archives)
        archives_future.emplace_back(std::async(RegisterArchive, i));

    for (auto& i : archives_future)
        i.get();
}

bool RegisterArchive(const std::string_view archive)
{
    for (auto& i : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(archive))
    {
        if (i.is_directory())
            continue;

        mapped_file map(i.path().string().c_str());
    }

    return true;
}
```

My question is, how can I map these files as quickly as possible?

I tried without std::async and tried other loading methods like FILE*, std::ifstream etc.

Comment: This code is throttled by the speed of the disk drive.  Speeding it up takes dollars, not code.

Comment: maybe you can combine all those files in a single file that you map once, or embed into your application resources, games don't usually have thousands of loose files for a reason.

Comment: What storage device do you have? HDD are inherently slow, especially for random access (i.e. operating with many files, due to seek times). Parallel/Async operations are generally not much faster on it. SSD can but it depends on the exact type of SSD. Did you profile your code and check you do not saturate the storage device?

Comment: I have an SSD. I am attempting to do file loader for a game (currently without any hash algorithms, pure directory). Perhaps a better solution would be to map the desired file once and then push its content into a cache container?

Comment: Install primocache, 64GB RAM and setup 40GB of read-only cache on the disk-drive you are using. I had 45GB/s bandwidth this way. If you make sure power-down never happens, you can also enable write-cache.

Comment: If you are writing a game, this means that this code will run on clients machine. Therefore you have no control over hardware. Assuming everyone has SSD is already a big mistake. So your options are limited. You can try lazy/background loading. So that you load only those files that are actually relevant. But most likely you just have too many files, if even under SSD it is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is to reduce file-system API calls for all redundant read-only file-read operations, you should use a cache.

Here is my multi-level cache implementation (direct mapped + lru) for requesting data while cache-miss is handled automatically:

[image]

Test code:

```
#include "CpuBenchmarker.h"
#include "LruClockCache.h"
#include "DirectMappedCache.h"
#include "CacheThreader.h"
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include<omp.h>
int main()
{
    std::atomic<size_t> total = 0;
    for (float benchmark = 2; benchmark >= 0.5f; benchmark *= 0.97f)
    {
        const int LLCsize = 1024 * 128;

        // randomly fill array
        std::vector<int> backingStore(5000000);
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 rng(rd());
        std::uniform_real_distribution<float> rnd(0, 5000000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
            backingStore[i] = rnd(rng);

        auto LLC = std::make_shared<LruClockCache<int, int>>(LLCsize,
            [&](int key) {
        
                // cache read-miss: runs when cache.get() does not find data in cache container
                // replace this with your file-read api (that is called only when data was not found in this cache)
                return backingStore[key];
            },
            [&](int key, int value) {

                // write-miss
                // don't use cache.set() because this is only a read-only mod!! but code is here just in case you want to build a read-write cache later
                backingStore[key] = value;
            });

        const int L2size = LLCsize / 4;
        const int L1size = L2size / 4; // L1 size has to be integer power of 2 !!!


        const size_t N = 100 * benchmark;
        const size_t repeat = 50 / (benchmark * benchmark * benchmark * benchmark * benchmark);
        const int numThreads = 20;
        const size_t totalWork = repeat * N * N * numThreads;
        CpuBenchmarker bench(totalWork * sizeof(int), "image pixels = " + std::to_string(N) + "x" + std::to_string(N) + "=" + std::to_string(N * N) +
            "   20 threads (LLC=" + std::to_string(LLCsize) +
            ", L2=" + std::to_string(L2size) +
            " x" + std::to_string(numThreads) + ", L1=" + std::to_string(L1size) + " x" + std::to_string(numThreads) + ")", totalWork);
        {

            #pragma omp parallel for  num_threads(20)
            for(int k=0;k<numThreads;k++)
                {
                        CacheThreader<LruClockCache,int,int> cache(LLC,L1size,L2size);
                        size_t subTotal = 0;
                        for (int m = 0; m < repeat; m++)
                            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                                {
                                    subTotal += cache.get(i + j * N);
                                }

                        total += subTotal;
                }

        }
    }
    std::cout << "sum of random numbers:" << total << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
image pixels = 105x105=11025   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 66022200 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 507.65 MB/s)      (throughput = 7.88 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 102x102=10404   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 61253300 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 597.88 MB/s)      (throughput = 6.69 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 99x99=9801   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 56015600 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 713.87 MB/s)      (throughput = 5.60 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 96x96=9216   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 52906400 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 836.13 MB/s)      (throughput = 4.78 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 93x93=8649   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 45101200 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1073.90 MB/s)      (throughput = 3.72 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 90x90=8100   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 37863000 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1386.26 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.89 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 87x87=7569   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 39471500 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1457.37 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.74 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 85x85=7225   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 42749400 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1500.79 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.67 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 82x82=6724   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 44301300 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1566.36 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.55 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 80x80=6400   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 50015600 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1535.52 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.60 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 77x77=5929   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 50565400 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1641.56 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.44 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 75x75=5625   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 54548700 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1682.90 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.38 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 73x73=5329   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 58442300 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1728.85 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.31 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 71x71=5041   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 63226100 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1766.81 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.26 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 68x68=4624   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 66321500 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1796.01 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.23 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 66x66=4356   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 72890800 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1792.82 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.23 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 64x64=4096   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 78564000 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1822.67 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.19 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 62x62=3844   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 85039200 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1840.65 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.17 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 60x60=3600   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 91043900 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1875.84 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.13 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 59x59=3481   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 101974900 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1884.30 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.12 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 57x57=3249   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 109013800 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1916.97 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.09 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 55x55=3025   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 118682500 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1910.59 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.09 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 53x53=2809   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 128109100 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1913.76 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.09 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 52x52=2704   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 142076600 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1933.65 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.07 nanoseconds per iteration)
image pixels = 50x50=2500   20 threads (LLC=131072, L2=32768 x20, L1=8192 x20): 151400200 nanoseconds     (bandwidth = 1953.76 MB/s)      (throughput = 2.05 nanoseconds per iteration)
sum of random numbers:2099302252640500
```

This is only for 4 bytes per request. With any file of 1kB+, you'd get the performance of your CPU's cache or RAM.

Implementation files (header-only but enable optimization flags, avx512 instruction set, C++14, etc):

CacheThreader.h:

```
/*
 * CacheThreader.h
 *
 *  Created on: Oct 7, 2021
 *      Author: tugrul
 */

#ifndef CACHETHREADER_H_
#define CACHETHREADER_H_


#include<vector>
#include<memory>
#include<thread>
#include<atomic>
#include"DirectMappedCache.h"
#include"LruClockCache.h"
 /* L1: direct mapped cache, for each thread
  * L2: LRU clock cache, for each thread (size must be integer-power of 2)
  * LLC: user-defined cache with thread-safe get/set methods that is slower but global
  * currently only 1 thread is supported
 */
template<template<typename, typename, typename> class Cache, typename CacheKey, typename CacheValue, typename CacheInternalCounterTypeInteger = size_t>
class CacheThreader
{
private:
    // last level cache, slow because of lock-guard
    std::shared_ptr<Cache<CacheKey, CacheValue, CacheInternalCounterTypeInteger>> LLC;
    std::shared_ptr<LruClockCache<CacheKey, CacheValue, CacheInternalCounterTypeInteger>> L2;
    std::shared_ptr<DirectMappedCache<CacheKey, CacheValue>> L1;


public:
    CacheThreader(std::shared_ptr<Cache<CacheKey, CacheValue, CacheInternalCounterTypeInteger>> cacheLLC, int sizeCacheL1, int sizeCacheL2)
    {

        LLC = cacheLLC;
        // backing-store of L1 is LLC
        L2 = std::make_shared<LruClockCache<CacheKey, CacheValue, CacheInternalCounterTypeInteger>>(sizeCacheL2, [this](CacheKey key) {

            return this->LLC->getThreadSafe(key);
            }, [this](CacheKey key, CacheValue value) {

                this->LLC->setThreadSafe(key, value);
            });
        L1 = std::make_shared<DirectMappedCache<CacheKey, CacheValue>>(sizeCacheL1, [this](CacheKey key) {

            return this->L2->get(key);
            }, [this](CacheKey key, CacheValue value) {

                this->L2->set(key, value);
            });
    }

    // get data from closest cache
    // currently only 1 thread supported
    inline
        const CacheValue get(CacheKey key) const
    {
        return L1->get(key);
    }

    // set data to closest cache
    // currently only 1 thread supported
    inline
        void set(CacheKey key, CacheValue value) const
    {
        L1->set(key, value);
    }

    // currently only 1 thread supported for read+write
    // only read-only usage for multi-threaded apps
    // must be called from all threads
    // does not flush LLC
    // LLC needs to be flushed manually by main-thread
    void flush()
    {
        L1->flush();
        L2->flush();
    }

    ~CacheThreader() {  }
};


#endif /* CACHETHREADER_H_ */
```

DirectMappedCache:

```
/*
 * DirectMappedCache.h
 *
 *  Created on: Oct 8, 2021
 *      Author: root
 */

#ifndef DIRECTMAPPEDCACHE_H_
#define DIRECTMAPPEDCACHE_H_

#include<vector>
#include<functional>
#include<mutex>


 /* Direct-mapped cache implementation
  * Only usable for integer type keys in range [0,maxPositive-1]
  *
  * CacheKey: type of key (only integers: int, char, size_t)
  * CacheValue: type of value that is bound to key (same as above)
  */
template<   typename CacheKey, typename CacheValue>
class DirectMappedCache
{
public:
    // allocates buffers for numElements number of cache slots/lanes
    // readMiss:    cache-miss for read operations. User needs to give this function
    //              to let the cache automatically get data from backing-store
    //              example: [&](MyClass key){ return redis.get(key); }
    //              takes a CacheKey as key, returns CacheValue as value
    // writeMiss:   cache-miss for write operations. User needs to give this function
    //              to let the cache automatically set data to backing-store
    //              example: [&](MyClass key, MyAnotherClass value){ redis.set(key,value); }
    //              takes a CacheKey as key and CacheValue as value
    // numElements: has to be integer-power of 2 (e.g. 2,4,8,16,...)
    DirectMappedCache(CacheKey numElements,
        const std::function<CacheValue(CacheKey)>& readMiss,
        const std::function<void(CacheKey, CacheValue)>& writeMiss,
        const int zenithShards = 4, /* unused for DirectMappedCache alone */
        const int zenithLane = 0 /* unused for DirectMappedCacheAlone*/
    ) :size(numElements), sizeM1(numElements - 1), loadData(readMiss), saveData(writeMiss)
    {
        // initialize buffers
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
        {
            valueBuffer.push_back(CacheValue());
            isEditedBuffer.push_back(0);
            keyBuffer.push_back(CacheKey() - 1);// mapping of 0+ allowed
        }
    }



    // get element from cache
    // if cache doesn't find it in buffers,
    // then cache gets data from backing-store
    // then returns the result to user
    // then cache is available from RAM on next get/set access with same key
    inline
        const CacheValue get(const CacheKey& key)  noexcept
    {
        return accessDirect(key, nullptr);
    }

    // only syntactic difference
    inline
        const std::vector<CacheValue> getMultiple(const std::vector<CacheKey>& key)  noexcept
    {
        const int n = key.size();
        std::vector<CacheValue> result(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            result[i] = accessDirect(key[i], nullptr);
        }
        return result;
    }


    // thread-safe but slower version of get()
    inline
        const CacheValue getThreadSafe(const CacheKey& key)  noexcept
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);
        return accessDirect(key, nullptr);
    }

    // set element to cache
    // if cache doesn't find it in buffers,
    // then cache sets data on just cache
    // writing to backing-store only happens when
    //                  another access evicts the cache slot containing this key/value
    //                  or when cache is flushed by flush() method
    // then returns the given value back
    // then cache is available from RAM on next get/set access with same key
    inline
        void set(const CacheKey& key, const CacheValue& val) noexcept
    {
        accessDirect(key, &val, 1);
    }

    // thread-safe but slower version of set()
    inline
        void setThreadSafe(const CacheKey& key, const CacheValue& val)  noexcept
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);
        accessDirect(key, &val, 1);
    }

    // use this before closing the backing-store to store the latest bits of data
    void flush()
    {
        try
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (isEditedBuffer[i] == 1)
                {
                    isEditedBuffer[i] = 0;
                    auto oldKey = keyBuffer[i];
                    auto oldValue = valueBuffer[i];
                    saveData(oldKey, oldValue);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& ex) { std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl; }
    }

    // direct mapped access
    // opType=0: get
    // opType=1: set
    CacheValue const accessDirect(const CacheKey& key, const CacheValue* value, const bool opType = 0)
    {

        // find tag mapped to the key
        CacheKey tag = key & sizeM1;

        // compare keys
        if (keyBuffer[tag] == key)
        {
            // cache-hit

            // "set"
            if (opType == 1)
            {
                isEditedBuffer[tag] = 1;
                valueBuffer[tag] = *value;
            }

            // cache hit value
            return valueBuffer[tag];
        }
        else // cache-miss
        {
            CacheValue oldValue = valueBuffer[tag];
            CacheKey oldKey = keyBuffer[tag];

            // eviction algorithm start
            if (isEditedBuffer[tag] == 1)
            {
                // if it is "get"
                if (opType == 0)
                {
                    isEditedBuffer[tag] = 0;
                }

                saveData(oldKey, oldValue);

                // "get"
                if (opType == 0)
                {
                    const CacheValue&& loadedData = loadData(key);
                    valueBuffer[tag] = loadedData;
                    keyBuffer[tag] = key;
                    return loadedData;
                }
                else /* "set" */
                {
                    valueBuffer[tag] = *value;
                    keyBuffer[tag] = key;
                    return *value;
                }
            }
            else // not edited
            {
                // "set"
                if (opType == 1)
                {
                    isEditedBuffer[tag] = 1;
                }

                // "get"
                if (opType == 0)
                {
                    const CacheValue&& loadedData = loadData(key);
                    valueBuffer[tag] = loadedData;
                    keyBuffer[tag] = key;
                    return loadedData;
                }
                else // "set"
                {
                    valueBuffer[tag] = *value;
                    keyBuffer[tag] = key;
                    return *value;
                }
            }

        }
    }


private:
    const CacheKey size;
    const CacheKey sizeM1;
    std::mutex mut;

    std::vector<CacheValue> valueBuffer;
    std::vector<unsigned char> isEditedBuffer;
    std::vector<CacheKey> keyBuffer;
    const std::function<CacheValue(CacheKey)>  loadData;
    const std::function<void(CacheKey, CacheValue)>  saveData;

};


#endif /* DIRECTMAPPEDCACHE_H_ */
```

LruClockCache.h:

```
#ifndef LRUCLOCKCACHE_H_
#define LRUCLOCKCACHE_H_

#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<functional>
#include<mutex>
#include<unordered_map>


 /* LRU-CLOCK-second-chance implementation
  *
  * LruKey: type of key (std::string, int, char, size_t, objects)
  * LruValue: type of value that is bound to key (same as above)
  * ClockHandInteger: just an optional optimization to reduce memory consumption when cache size is equal to or less than 255,65535,4B-1,...
  */
template<   typename LruKey, typename LruValue, typename ClockHandInteger = size_t>
class LruClockCache
{
public:
    // allocates circular buffers for numElements number of cache slots
    // readMiss:    cache-miss for read operations. User needs to give this function
    //              to let the cache automatically get data from backing-store
    //              example: [&](MyClass key){ return redis.get(key); }
    //              takes a LruKey as key, returns LruValue as value
    // writeMiss:   cache-miss for write operations. User needs to give this function
    //              to let the cache automatically set data to backing-store
    //              example: [&](MyClass key, MyAnotherClass value){ redis.set(key,value); }
    //              takes a LruKey as key and LruValue as value
    LruClockCache(ClockHandInteger numElements,
        const std::function<LruValue(LruKey)>& readMiss,
        const std::function<void(LruKey, LruValue)>& writeMiss) :size(numElements), loadData(readMiss), saveData(writeMiss)
    {
        ctr = 0;
        // 50% phase difference between eviction and second-chance hands of the "second-chance" CLOCK algorithm
        ctrEvict = numElements / 2;

        //loadData=readMiss;
        //saveData=writeMiss;

        // initialize circular buffers
        for (ClockHandInteger i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
        {
            valueBuffer.push_back(LruValue());
            chanceToSurviveBuffer.push_back(0);
            isEditedBuffer.push_back(0);
            keyBuffer.push_back(LruKey());
        }
        mapping.reserve(numElements);
    }



    // get element from cache
    // if cache doesn't find it in circular buffers,
    // then cache gets data from backing-store
    // then returns the result to user
    // then cache is available from RAM on next get/set access with same key
    inline
        const LruValue get(const LruKey& key)  noexcept
    {
        return accessClock2Hand(key, nullptr);
    }

    // only syntactic difference
    inline
        const std::vector<LruValue> getMultiple(const std::vector<LruKey>& key)  noexcept
    {
        const int n = key.size();
        std::vector<LruValue> result(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            result[i] = accessClock2Hand(key[i], nullptr);
        }
        return result;
    }


    // thread-safe but slower version of get()
    inline
        const LruValue getThreadSafe(const LruKey& key) noexcept
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);
        return accessClock2Hand(key, nullptr);
    }

    // set element to cache
    // if cache doesn't find it in circular buffers,
    // then cache sets data on just cache
    // writing to backing-store only happens when
    //                  another access evicts the cache slot containing this key/value
    //                  or when cache is flushed by flush() method
    // then returns the given value back
    // then cache is available from RAM on next get/set access with same key
    inline
        void set(const LruKey& key, const LruValue& val) noexcept
    {
        accessClock2Hand(key, &val, 1);
    }

    // thread-safe but slower version of set()
    inline
        void setThreadSafe(const LruKey& key, const LruValue& val)  noexcept
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);
        accessClock2Hand(key, &val, 1);
    }

    // use this before closing the backing-store to store the latest bits of data
    void flush()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);
        for (auto mp = mapping.cbegin(); mp != mapping.cend() /* not hoisted */; /* no increment */)
        {
            if (isEditedBuffer[mp->second] == 1)
            {
                isEditedBuffer[mp->second] = 0;
                auto oldKey = keyBuffer[mp->second];
                auto oldValue = valueBuffer[mp->second];
                saveData(oldKey, oldValue);
                mapping.erase(mp++);    // or "it = m.erase(it)" since C++11
            }
            else
            {
                ++mp;
            }
        }
    }

    // CLOCK algorithm with 2 hand counters (1 for second chance for a cache slot to survive, 1 for eviction of cache slot)
    // opType=0: get
    // opType=1: set
    LruValue const accessClock2Hand(const LruKey& key, const LruValue* value, const bool opType = 0)
    {

        // check if it is a cache-hit (in-cache)
        typename std::unordered_map<LruKey, ClockHandInteger>::iterator it = mapping.find(key);
        if (it != mapping.end())
        {

            chanceToSurviveBuffer[it->second] = 1;
            if (opType == 1)
            {
                isEditedBuffer[it->second] = 1;
                valueBuffer[it->second] = *value;
            }
            return valueBuffer[it->second];
        }
        else // could not found key in cache, so searching in circular-buffer starts
        {
            long long ctrFound = -1;
            LruValue oldValue;
            LruKey oldKey;
            while (ctrFound == -1)
            {
                // second-chance hand lowers the "chance" status down if its 1 but slot is saved from eviction
                // 1 more chance to be in a cache-hit until eviction-hand finds this
                if (chanceToSurviveBuffer[ctr] > 0)
                {
                    chanceToSurviveBuffer[ctr] = 0;
                }

                // circular buffer has no bounds
                ctr++;
                if (ctr >= size)
                {
                    ctr = 0;
                }

                // unlucky slot is selected for eviction by eviction hand
                if (chanceToSurviveBuffer[ctrEvict] == 0)
                {
                    ctrFound = ctrEvict;
                    oldValue = valueBuffer[ctrFound];
                    oldKey = keyBuffer[ctrFound];
                }

                // circular buffer has no bounds
                ctrEvict++;
                if (ctrEvict >= size)
                {
                    ctrEvict = 0;
                }
            }

            // eviction algorithm start
            if (isEditedBuffer[ctrFound] == 1)
            {
                // if it is "get"
                if (opType == 0)
                {
                    isEditedBuffer[ctrFound] = 0;
                }

                saveData(oldKey, oldValue);

                // "get"
                if (opType == 0)
                {
                    const LruValue&& loadedData = loadData(key);
                    mapping.erase(keyBuffer[ctrFound]);
                    valueBuffer[ctrFound] = loadedData;
                    chanceToSurviveBuffer[ctrFound] = 0;

                    mapping.emplace(key, ctrFound);
                    keyBuffer[ctrFound] = key;

                    return loadedData;
                }
                else /* "set" */
                {
                    mapping.erase(keyBuffer[ctrFound]);


                    valueBuffer[ctrFound] = *value;
                    chanceToSurviveBuffer[ctrFound] = 0;

                    mapping.emplace(key, ctrFound);
                    keyBuffer[ctrFound] = key;
                    return *value;
                }
            }
            else // not edited
            {
                // "set"
                if (opType == 1)
                {
                    isEditedBuffer[ctrFound] = 1;
                }

                // "get"
                if (opType == 0)
                {
                    const LruValue&& loadedData = loadData(key);
                    mapping.erase(keyBuffer[ctrFound]);
                    valueBuffer[ctrFound] = loadedData;
                    chanceToSurviveBuffer[ctrFound] = 0;

                    mapping.emplace(key, ctrFound);
                    keyBuffer[ctrFound] = key;

                    return loadedData;
                }
                else // "set"
                {
                    mapping.erase(keyBuffer[ctrFound]);


                    valueBuffer[ctrFound] = *value;
                    chanceToSurviveBuffer[ctrFound] = 0;

                    mapping.emplace(key, ctrFound);
                    keyBuffer[ctrFound] = key;
                    return *value;
                }
            }

        }
    }


private:
    const ClockHandInteger size;
    std::mutex mut;
    std::unordered_map<LruKey, ClockHandInteger> mapping;
    std::vector<LruValue> valueBuffer;
    std::vector<unsigned char> chanceToSurviveBuffer;
    std::vector<unsigned char> isEditedBuffer;
    std::vector<LruKey> keyBuffer;
    const std::function<LruValue(LruKey)>  loadData;
    const std::function<void(LruKey, LruValue)>  saveData;
    ClockHandInteger ctr;
    ClockHandInteger ctrEvict;
};

#endif /* LRUCLOCKCACHE_H_ */
```

CpuBenchmarker.h:

```
#ifndef CPUBENCHMARKER_H_
#define CPUBENCHMARKER_H_

#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

 // RAII type benchmarker
class CpuBenchmarker
{
public:
    CpuBenchmarker() :CpuBenchmarker(0, "", 0)
    {
        measurementTarget = nullptr;
    }

    CpuBenchmarker(size_t bytesToBench) :CpuBenchmarker(bytesToBench, "", 0)
    {
        measurementTarget = nullptr;
    }

    CpuBenchmarker(size_t bytesToBench, std::string infoExtra) :CpuBenchmarker(bytesToBench, infoExtra, 0)
    {
        measurementTarget = nullptr;
    }

    CpuBenchmarker(size_t bytesToBench, std::string infoExtra, size_t countForThroughput) :t1(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()))
    {
        bytes = bytesToBench;
        info = infoExtra;
        count = countForThroughput;
        measurementTarget = nullptr;
    }

    // writes elapsed time (in seconds) to this variable upon destruction
    void addTimeWriteTarget(double* measurement)
    {
        measurementTarget = measurement;
    }

    ~CpuBenchmarker()
    {
        std::chrono::nanoseconds t2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
        size_t t = t2.count() - t1.count();
        if (measurementTarget != nullptr)
        {
            *measurementTarget = t / 1000000000.0; // seconds
        }
        if (info != std::string(""))
            std::cout << info << ": ";
        std::cout << t << " nanoseconds    ";
        if (bytes > 0)
        {
            std::cout << " (bandwidth = ";
            std::cout << std::fixed;
            std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
            std::cout << (bytes / (((double)t) / 1000000000.0)) / 1000000.0 << " MB/s)     ";
        }
        if (count > 0)
        {
            std::cout << " (throughput = ";
            std::cout << std::fixed;
            std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
            std::cout << (((double)t) / count) << " nanoseconds per iteration) ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::chrono::nanoseconds t1;
    size_t bytes;
    size_t count;
    std::string info;
    double* measurementTarget;
};

#endif /* CPUBENCHMARKER_H_ */
```

---

If you need read+write coherence in multithreaded use, you can look at implementation here:

https://github.com/tugrul512bit/LruClockCache/blob/main/AsyncCache.h

---

If you are using just a single thread, then it's better to use non-thread-safe version like this:

```
using MyKeyType = std::string;
using MyValueType = MinecraftChunk;

LruClockCache<MyKeyType,MyValueType> cache(1024*5,[&](MyKeyType key){ 
  // cache miss (read)
  // access data-store (network, hdd, graphics card, anything that is slower than RAM or higher-latency than RAM-latency x2)
  return readChunkFromHDD(key);
  },[&](MyKeyType key,MyValueType value){ 
  
  // cache miss (write)
  // access data-store
  writeChunkToHDD(key,value);
});

// cache handles all cace-miss functions automatically
MinecraftChunk chunk = cache.get("world coordinates 1500 35 2000");

// cache handles all cace-miss functions automatically
cache.set("world coordinates 1502 35 1999",chunk);

cache.flush(); // clears all pending-writes in the cache and writes to backing-store
```

it's also automatically coherent when you set/write something through the cache.